# How to post an array of values using `UrlFetchApp.fetch` with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Tags: google-apps-script

I fail to post an array of values unless I provide the array key. (see the output in my code)

Could someone tell the proper way to post an array with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

```js
function test() {
  function post(payload) {
    const url = 'https://my.php.post.server/';
    // Content of PHP: var_dump($_POST['tags']);
    const options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'payload': payload
    }
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    const content = response.getContentText();
    console.log(content);
  }

  post({
    'tags': [1, 2]
  });
  // string(28) "[Ljava.lang.Object;@71c0475b"

  post({
    'tags[]': [1, 2]
  });
  // array(1) {
  //   [0]=>
  //   string(27) "[Ljava.lang.Object;@9bc5c1d"
  // }

  post({
    'tags': 1,
    'tags': 2
  });
  // string(3) "2.0"
  
  post({
    'tags[]': 1,
    'tags[]': 2
  });
  // array(1) {
  //   [0]=>
  //   string(3) "2.0"
  // }

  post({
    'tags[0]': 1,
    'tags[1]': 2
  });
  // array(2) {
  //   [1]=>
  //   string(3) "2.0"
  //   [0]=>
  //   string(3) "1.0"
  // }
}
```

Comment: In order to confirm the specification of the API you want to use, can you provide the document of the API you want to use?

Comment: @Tanaike The same parameter `tags[]` [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/pardot/guide/emails-v4.html#email-list-send)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided document, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, from [your provided document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/pardot/guide/emails-v4.html#email-list-send), I proposed the following modification.

From your provided document, I found the following sample curl command.

```
curl https://pi.pardot.com/api/email/version/4/do/send \
--header "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN>" \
--header'Pardot-Business-Unit-Id: <BUSINESS UNIT ID>'
--data-urlencode campaign_id=12345 \
--data-urlencode from_assigned_user=1 \
--data-urlencode email_template_id=6789 \
--data-urlencode list_ids[]=123 \
--data-urlencode list_ids[]=456 \
--data-urlencode list_ids[]=789 \
--data-urlencode list_ids[]=101 \
--data-urlencode suppression_list_ids[]=987 \
--data-urlencode suppression_list_ids[]=654 \
--data-urlencode tags[]=new_prospect_email \
--data-urlencode tags[]=cart_abandoned \
--data-urlencode tags[]=subtotal_over_200 \
--data-urlencode scheduled_time=2021-10-31T17:00:00-0400 \
--data-urlencode format=json
```

In this case, I thought that when you want to use `{'tags[]': [1, 2]}`, it is required to request as the form data by the content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. In order to achieve this using Google Apps Script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, in order to convert the object of `{'tags[]': [1, 2]}` to the query parameter, I used [this sample script](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/07/12/adding-query-parameters-to-url-using-google-apps-script/).

```js
function test() {
  // This is from https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/07/12/adding-query-parameters-to-url-using-google-apps-script/
  String.prototype.addQuery = function(obj) {
    return this + Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(p, e, i) {
      return p + (i == 0 ? "?" : "&") +
        (Array.isArray(obj[e]) ? obj[e].reduce(function(str, f, j) {
          return str + e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(f) + (j != obj[e].length - 1 ? "&" : "")
        },"") : e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[e]));
    },"");
  }

  function post(payload) {
    const url = 'https://my.php.post.server/';
    // Content of PHP: var_dump($_POST['tags']);
    const options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'payload': "".addQuery(payload).replace("?", ""),
    }
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    const content = response.getContentText();
    console.log(content);
  }

  post({"tags[]": [1, 2]});
}
```

- By this modification, `{"tags[]": [1, 2]}` is sent as the form data.

#### Note:

- **This is a simple sample script to explain for achieving your goal. Please modify this for your situation.**
- When `addQuery` is modified to your situation, it becomes as follows.

  ```
    const convertQuery = obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((p, e) =>
      p + (Array.isArray(obj[e]) ? obj[e].reduce((str, f, j) =>
        str + e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(f) + (j != obj[e].length - 1 ? "&" : ""),"") : e + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[e])) ,"");

    function post(payload) {
      const url = 'https://my.php.post.server/';
      // Content of PHP: var_dump($_POST['tags']);
      const options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'payload': convertQuery(payload)
      }
      const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      const content = response.getContentText();
      console.log(content);
    }

    post({"tags[]": [1, 2]});
  ```

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean that there is no built-in function which could handle an array with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: Besides, if I only have `tags` being an array and with length of 2, as in my example, would `{'tags[0]': 1, 'tags[1]': 2}` be a 'proper' method? Would there be something simple and 'better'?

Comment: @idfurw Thank you for replying. About `Do you mean that GAS could not handle an array with application/x-www-form-urlencoded?`, in this case, at Google Apps Script, it seems that `{"tags[]": [1, 2]}` cannot be directly used as `payload` bacause `[1, 2]` is an object. But, when `{"tags[]": [1, 2]}` is converted to `tags[]=1&tags[]=2`, this can be sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. If this explanation is not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @idfurw When your API can use `{'tags[0]': 1, 'tags[1]': 2}` as the form data, this can be simply achieved. But when I saw your provided document, it seems that it is required to be `{"tags[]": [1, 2]}`. So I converted it to `tags[]=1&tags[]=2` as the query parameter.

Comment: I have just tried `{'tags[0]': 1, 'tags[1]': 2}` and it works but your answer is useful. Thank you.

Comment: @idfurw Thank you for replying. I couldn't test your API. But, from your reply, I could know that `{'tags[]': [1, 2]}` can be used as `{'tags[0]': 1, 'tags[1]': 2}`. I'm not sure whether this is the general specification of this. But, when I have the same situation in other APIs, I would like to test this. Thank you, too.

Comment: what happens if tags contains dictionaries?
I'm trying to post a urlencoded form with an element `{'tags':[{'tagname':'name','tagval':'value'}]}` without success :(

Comment: @Nacho R About your question of `what happens if tags contains dictionaries? I'm trying to post a urlencoded form with an element {'tags':[{'tagname':'name','tagval':'value'}]} without success :(`, I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. And, this question is not your question. So, please post it as a new question. By this, it will help users think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?